# Are JavaScript Arrays significantly smaller than Objects on the heap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, v8

I'm working with (network) graphs in the browser and was wondering if I can significantly reduce memory usage by changing the way I represent them.

I was thinking of changing the representation of the edges from:

```js
{from : string, to : string, weight : number, bi : boolean}
```

To:

```js
[string, string, number, boolean]
```

I recognize that the serialized `Object` sizes and `Array` sizes for this particular use case are not that different, particularly if I shorten my keys. But, I'm curious if there is a significant difference between the size of `Objects` and `Arrays` on the heap in most browsers. If I'm most concerned about browsers running `V8`, is there a way to test this in `Node`?

Note: without the graph portion of my application, my JS heap was already a little large (15 mb for my logic + 50mb for a couple frames). So, there is a bit of justification beyond my curiosity for trying something like this out.

Comment: V8 has various ways of optimizing arrays of all one type (which is not what you are proposing) and various ways of optimizing objects where you create a lot of objects that are identical in structure (which is what you have).  Basically, V8 can put them into C-like structures as long as they are all identical.  So, as with many V8 optimizations, you can only really see what does and doesn't benefit you by testing your real world code and measuring.  Don't try it with a test bed because you need to know that the optimizations come into play in  your real code.

Comment: It is possible the object is more efficient because of the optimizations that V8 can apply to them if they are all identical in structure (with no variants).  You will have to measure to find out.

Comment: @jfriend00 Are you recommending I only test this against my actual application or just to not even bother?

Comment: If this type of optimization is really important to you, I'm recommending you test in your actual application to compare.

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it. Thanks!

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not concerned about speed. I'm hoping this is more big picture if it actually does make a difference in memory usage.

Comment: Basically all of the article is still applicable, even if it's not speed. Do take a good note of the first part - *test* both your options *with realistic data* and *under realistic circumstances*. As the article says: "race your horses". Only instead of speed, you're looking for size but it's the same thing - you want to know which one is better, in the end.

Comment: @VLAZ Gotcha. Misread the subtext haha. Been burned a couple times before asking JavaScript optimization questions.

Comment: My humble expreience on dealing with JS arrays for a long time is that they are good and fast and optimized like hell. Use all provided prototype functions as they are intended. In short... dont bother much about `a.unshift()` and `a.push()`.

Comment: What you might be interested in learning more about is regularly referred to as "hidden classes" in V8 (where it creates C-like compact data structures for multiple objects with the same properties and types of values) and you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@yashschandra/hidden-v8-optimizations-hidden-classes-and-inline-caching-736a09c2e9eb) and [here](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties) or in many other articles on the topic.

Comment: @Redu - Arrays of mixed type data are not as optimized as arrays of all the same type data.  This will have to be resolved through testing to find out which optimizations apply to the array and which apply to the objects as there are various optimizations for both.  This is the "fun" of an optimizing compiler in any higher level language that doesn't allow you to directly specify the in-memory format (basically anything higher level than C/C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

What I'd expect is that the objects are slightly smaller than the arrays in this case. I'd also expect that the difference only matters if you have *a lot* of objects.

The reason is V8's "hidden classes" system, where the names of the properties are only stored once and shared by all objects with the same "shape", so each object needs 3 pointers (object header) + 4 pointers for the properties, with each pointer being 4 bytes that's a total of 7*4 = 28 bytes. The length of the property names does not affect the per-object memory requirements. Arrays have one more property (`.length`), and their elements will be stored in a separate backing store, so the total memory consumption for each array should be 3 (object header) + 1 (length) + 2 (backing store header) + 4 (elements) pointers = 10 pointers or 40 bytes.

In a simpler JavaScript engine where all objects are implemented as dictionaries, arrays might indeed save some memory, because each object would store the property names, at least as a pointer to a shared string -- unless, of course, arrays are also implemented as dictionaries in such an engine, in which case they'd again be a bit bigger because they have the additional `length` property.
Depending on what else you do with your objects, you could make V8 migrate them to dictionary mode (because hidden classes have many benefits and also some disadvantages in some cases), but it's more likely you'll encounter the situation described above.

So, as always for performance and memory questions, the only way to be sure is to implement both approaches *in your real app (not in a simplified microbenchmark)* and measure the impact. If you can't measure a difference, then there is no difference to worry about.

Comment: Haven't tested yet. But, just curious, how would I make V8 migrate my objects to dictionary mode?

Comment: Adding and removing too many properties will cause that eventually. If you know that you'll want to add and remove many properties, use a `Map` instead of an object. Just to clarify, if I understand the case at hand correctly, dictionary mode would cost you both memory and performance, so it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to attempt to experiment with that.